# What kind of file does /etc/inputrc belong to?

Tags: bash, configuration, readline, etc

Seems like that the `/etc/inputrc` file conforms to the shell script syntax. But the file name does not end with a `.sh`. The first line in the file does not have a `#!`, either.

Is it another kind of file?

And does that kind of file go in parallel with the `.sh`?

Does it run like a shell script?

Does it have a naming convention like the `.sh` suffix?

Comment: Yes, I understand that /etc/inputrc is one of the run control files together with /etc/profile, ~/.bashrc, and many many more. What I want to get clear is that is the inputrc one of, say, in Windows, .txt, .jpg, .docx, or anything like that. And does it have a specific syntax in contrast to the shell script.

Comment: Your model of file categories with a mandatory, well-defined suffix ("extension") for each category is simply inadequate, even in MS-DOS where they at least try to pretend that it kind of works.

Answer (score 11):

`/etc/inputrc` is the system-wide configuration file for GNU readline, a library implementing a line editor used by many applications like `gdb`, `python`, GNU `bc`...

You can find documentation about it in the `readline(3)` man page or the [official GNU readline documentation online](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9).

`readline` is being maintained by the same person (Chet Ramey) as `bash`. `bash` and `readline` development have been closely tied. However, note that it's a modified version of `readline` that `bash` uses (but still reads `/etc/inputrc` and `~/.inputrc`) since the generic `readline` library can't cover for all the needs of `bash`.

`/etc/inputrc` is just some configuration file. The name doesn't imply what the content or format may be. Others configuration file names follow the same pattern like `netrc`, `screenrc`, `wgetrc`... and the original meaning of *rc* (*run commands*) doesn't really apply there either. `rc` in those instances, should be seen as the same as `.conf` or `.cfg`. Those files in `/etc` that have a `rc` suffix often have a pendant as a dot file in the user's home directory (like `~/.bashrc`, `~/.inputrc`, `~/.screenrc`). See also the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc_file) for more information.

Comment: I always thought `rc` is for `reconfiguration` (similar to `conf`).

Comment: Thant's really funny! Never though it can be stand for This! :))

Answer (score 1):

The inputrc file handles keyboard mapping for specific situations. This file is the startup file used by Readline — the input-related library — used by Bash and most other shells.

[Found it here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lfs/LFS-BOOK-6.1.1-HTML/chapter07/inputrc.html)

Comment: Can I conclude that a startup file is another kind of file which goes similar to shell script?

Comment: It is not used by most other shells. `bash` comes with its own variant of readline. readline is being maintained by the same guy as `bash`. `tcsh`, `zsh`, `ksh`, `fish`, `ash`, `yash` do not use `readline`. The Linux ports of `rc` and `es` do. `readline` is used by countless non-shell applications though.